# react-native NumericInput component doesn't work on web browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, react-native

On the web browser, I have the + and - overlapping and clicking on them doesn't do anything. Also we can't see the number.

[image]

So I tried to run it on android and it worked properly.
But why isn't it working on the web browser ?

The code is however basic.

```
import React from 'react';

import { View, Text, Buttonn, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import NumericInput from 'react-native-numeric-input'

const style = require('@app/components/common/styles').style;


export default class HomeSettingsScreen extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.navigation = props.navigation;

                this.state = {
                        homeCitiesNumber: 10,
                }
        }

        render = () => {
                return (
                        <View>
                                <View style={style.container}>
                                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: 'black', width: '100%', fontFamily: 'DMSans-Regular' }}>
                                                <Text style={style.titleContainer}>Settings</Text>
                                        </View>
                                </View>
                                <NumericInput
                                        value={this.state.homeCitiesNumber} 
                                        onChange={value => this.setState({homeCitiesNumber: value})}
                                        minValue={0}
                                        maxValue={25}
                                        /> 
                                <NumericInput onChange={value => console.log(value)} />
                        </View> 
                )
        }

}
```